# A regex in Java. Latin letters, digits, dots, and minus signs

Tags: java, regex

There is a user login, and the requirements are the following:

- The login must start with a Latin letter.
- The login must finish with either a Latin letter or a digit.
- There may also be digits, dots, and minus signs in the login.
- Min. login length is 1.
- Max. login length is 20.

Here is my Java code.

```
boolean checkLogin(String login) {
        final int maxLength = 20;
        if (login == null || login.isEmpty() || login.length() > maxLength) {
            return false;
        }

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z][a-z\\d\\.\\-]*[a-z\\d]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(login);
        return matcher.matches();
}
```

Is everything OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That regex does not meet the requirements of your rules... so ... No, it is not OK.

The missing aspect is that the regex requires at least two characters, but the rules say one char is OK.

Also, I don't like that the last group has the `+` on it. While it is accurate in the sense that the last characters can be alpha/digit, it implies that the rule is for more than just the last character.

Another problem is that you allow logins of more than 20 characters.

A more meaningful/accurate regex would be:

```
^[a-z]([a-z\\d\\.\\-]{0,18}[a-z\\d])?$
```

Which requires 1 character, and then up to 18 'broad' characters followed by a constrained alpha/digit character.

EDIT:
2 things:

1. Aseem has rightly pointed out that the preceding if-condition essentially makes the `{0,18}` limit redundant. My preference is to keep it there for clarity, but, it does create duplication of logic which may lead to bugs later (How did I miss that the lenght is checked first... hmmm). Your call as to whether you should replace the `{0,18}` with just `{*}`.
2. The Pattern should be made static. There is no reason to re-compile the pattern for every call to the method (Patterns are thread-safe):

   ```
   private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
           "^[a-z]([a-z\\d\\.\\-]{0,18}[a-z\\d])?$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

   private static final int maxLength = 20;

   boolean checkLogin(String login) {

       if (login == null || login.isEmpty() || login.length() > maxLength) {
           return false;
       }

       return pattern.matcher(login).matches();
   }
   ```

Comment: How does it allow logins of more than 20 characters? Isn't that checked in the `if`? Your approach is better but..

Comment: @AseemBansal - yes, the preceding if condition makes the `{0,18}` redundant... hmmm. The {0,18} can be replaced with `*` but there is a **very** slight performance benefit for the exactly-20 char login if you constrain to 18.... so slight it's not worth considering....

Comment: @rolfl, Why do use a group in your reply? It could look like this **^[a-z][a-z\d\.\-]{0,18}[a-z\d]$** I guess that the group makes it work faster

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev That makes it minimum 2 characters

Comment: @AseemBansal, thanks! **^[a-z][a-z]$** means that there must be at least two characters

Comment: @AseemBansal I have edited to add a couple more suggestions.

Comment: It's Aseem with a single **s**. The option to precompile it is good but the reusablity is lost in case same rules are applied but the minimum and maximum length are different. So having the `if` can actually be a good thing. The `Pattern` will be precompiled and you get the option of different bounds on length. Currently the edited code has redundancy for checking length.

Comment: @rolfl, I edited my code. I agree that there is no reason to recompile `Pattern` every time, and `{0,18}` is better than my `if` because it really keeps logic at one place.

Comment: @AseemBansal, the min/max length won't be different; therefore, I can use `{0,18}`

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev It's better to have reusable code. Later if you extended it then making changes later can introduce subtle bugs which can make your life hell. If you leave reuseability out of the picture then your life will be spent debugging code instead of writing code. But it's your code and you know it better than me. I may just be thinking too much :P

Comment: @AseemBansal - to make this code reusable, I would still leave it as a private-stat-final, but make it a call to a method like: `Pattern pattern = MyUtilities.passwordpattern(maxPassLength);` or something.

Answer (score 4):

A good naming convention for predicates (functions that return a boolean and that have no side-effects) is `isBlah()`.  I would rename the method to `isValidLogin()`.

If you would like to use a regular expression, then let the regular expression do the hard work.  You can even limit the length using the regex.  The only thing the regular expression matcher can't handle is a null string.

Compile the pattern just once as a class constant.

Your regex is wrong.  Within a character class (i.e., between `[…]`), the language is different: `.` is a literal dot.  The hyphen is also literal if it comes at the end of the character class.  Therefore, no backslashes are necessary.  Also, your regex requires at least two characters, though your rules require just one.

Here is how I would write it:

```
private static final LOGIN_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("^[a-z](?:[a-z0-9.-]{0,18}[a-z0-9])?$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

boolean isValidLogin(String login) {
    return (login != null) && LOGIN_PATTERN.matcher(login).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexes

```
"^[a-z][a-z\\d\\.\\-]*[a-z\\d]+$"
```

```
"^[a-z][a-z0-9.-]*[a-z0-9]$"
```

are basically the same. True story.